# With Git, how to find who modified directory contents?

Tags: git

How can I find who last modified directory contents in Git? In an ideal world, I would like the output of `ls` prepended with the same stuff `git blame` produces. So for each tracked directory of the repository, find who last modified it.

To give an example, say this is the directory structure:

```
|-project
  |-dir-a
    |-file1.txt (modified by Alice in commit 1)
    |-file2.txt (modified by Bob in commit 2)
    |-file5.txt (modified by Carl in commit 4)
  |-dir-b
    |-file3.txt (modified by Alice in commit 3)
    |-file4.txt (modified by Alice in commit 3)
```

Then the script I'm looking for, when run in `project/`, will produce something like this:

```
$ unknown-command
commit4 Carl  dir-a
commit3 Alice dir-b
```

I'm not afraid of scripting, so it doesn't need to be a complete solution.

Comment: The title and body of your question kinda contradict each other. The title of your question is asking: *For each "tracked" directory of the repo, find who last modified it*. However, as I understand it, the body of your question is essentially asking: *For each committer of the repo, find the directory that s/he last modified*. The latter would force you to walk along the entire commit DAG, which may take a while in big repos. Which one do you want?

Comment: @Jubobs You found a pattern that I did not intend. I changed the example to avoid the pattern. I'm really just interested in the directories.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean like this?

```
for i in $(ls -1); do git log --format=format:"%h  %<(28)%ai %<(30)%an $i" -n1 $i; done
```

... produces:

```
7a29533  2015-02-27 19:19:45 +0100    David Ostrovsky                BUCK
6f083b8  2014-11-22 11:16:14 +0100    David Ostrovsky                bucklets
686bfea  2014-12-04 14:23:30 +0900    David Pursehouse               contrib
23571ab  2008-11-14 16:56:58 -0800    Shawn O. Pearce                COPYING
...
```

Edit: Thanks to ghoti for the comment - parsing `ls` is indeed a bad idea.
This version works with whitespaces in filenames:

```
 find . -maxdepth 1 -exec git log -n1 --format=format:"%h  %<(28)%ai %<(30)%an {}" {} \;
```

Comment: I think the OP wants to answer: *For each committer of the repo, find the directory that s/he last modified?* Which is trickier. In the output, each committer would only be listed once.

Comment: Could you perhaps use `for i in *` rather than looping the way you've done it?  What happens if files have spaces in their names?  *[Parsing ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)* is not safe.

Answer (score 3):

> How can I find who last modified directory contents in Git?

If, by "directory contents", you mean "working tree" (a.k.a. [*working directory*](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Git-Basics#The-Three-States)), the answer is plain and simple: you cannot. At least, not with Git only.

The reason is that, in Git, one's name only gets attached to changes when one creates a [commit object](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Internals-Git-Objects#Commit-Objects). Merely making local changes or even staging changes (i.e. modifying the index) is not associated with any name. For all Git knows, your grandma may have done it.

Comment: Of course I am only interested in the names for committed changes. `git blame` also cannot tell you who made uncomitted changes.

Comment: @FrankKusters In that case, you should edit your question for clarification. What do you mean by "directory contents"? Do you mean a breakdown of who last changed each tracked file?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for " git log --name-status" ?

```
$ git lg --name-status
* 67475d0 - (HEAD, origin/master, master) 2015-04-09-rename-files-in-batch.html <lgfang@5 days ago>|
| A     _posts/util/2015-04-09-rename-files-in-batch.html

* 2098891 - 2015-04-07-kindle-dedrm: add <lgfang@6 days ago>|
| A     _posts/rec/2015-04-07-kindle-dedrm.html

* a96fc4e - 2015-04-07-snmptrapd: add <lgfang@6 days ago>|
| A     _posts/network/2015-04-07-snmptrapd.html

* 059342f - 2014-03-26-java-cover: add <lgfang@8 days ago>|
```

Comment: No, although I can understand why you would understand my question that way. I'll make my question more clear.